# SAPUI5 - Is it possible to set a default select list key?

Tags: sapui5

I've provided a quick example, but how do I select a default time (select item) as 05:00 for example? Please not that I've needed to capture time with the select (and not the timepicker) because our customer wanted to force 15 minute intervals).

```
<Select id="openingTime" selectedKey="{SearchResults>startTime1}"
                                 valueFormat="HH:mm" displayFormat="HH:mm"
                                 change="onTimeChangedOpening"
                                 visible="{SearchResults>isOpen}" valueState="{SearchResults>startTimeValid}"
                                placeholder="Enter Opening Time">
                            <core:ListItem key="" text="Select"/>
                            <core:Item key="00:00" text="00:00"/>
                            <core:Item key="00:15" text="00:15"/>
                            <core:Item key="00:30" text="00:30"/>
                            <core:Item key="00:45" text="00:45"/>
                            <core:Item key="01:00" text="01:00"/>
                            <core:Item key="01:15" text="01:15"/>
                            <core:Item key="01:30" text="01:30"/>
                            <core:Item key="01:45" text="01:45"/>
                            <core:Item key="02:00" text="02:00"/>
                            <core:Item key="02:15" text="02:15"/>
                            <core:Item key="02:30" text="02:30"/>
                            <core:Item key="02:45" text="02:45"/>
                            <core:Item key="03:00" text="03:00"/>
                            <core:Item key="03:15" text="03:15"/>
                            <core:Item key="03:30" text="03:30"/>
                            <core:Item key="03:45" text="03:45"/>
                            <core:Item key="04:00" text="04:00"/>
                            <core:Item key="04:15" text="04:15"/>
                            <core:Item key="04:30" text="04:30"/>
                            <core:Item key="04:45" text="04:45"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by setting:

```
selectedKey = "05:00"
```

You also need to add this to:

```
<core:Item key="05:00" text="05:00"/>
```

Here is jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/cucayaketa/1/edit?html,js,output). You can changed selected value in the line:

```
oSelect.setSelectedKey("B");
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set default key by below code

```
                       <Select
                        forceSelection="true"
                        selectedKey="{SearchResults/0/startTime1}"
                        items="{
                            path: '/SearchResults'

                        }">
                        <core:Item key="{/startTime1}" text="{startTime1}" />
                    </Select>
```